Why is addDeviceIdToIndexDb returning undefined in my React Hook test using fake-indexeddb
I am testing a custom React hook (useIndexDb) that interacts with IndexedDB. The hook is supposed to add a deviceId to the IndexedDB database. However, when I call addDeviceIdToIndexDb in my test, the result seems to be undefined, and the test fails when trying to verify the stored value.
Here’s the relevant code:


import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { openDB } from 'idb';
import 'fake-indexeddb/auto';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from '../../redux-store/authSlice';
import globalReducer from '../../redux-store/globalSlice';
import progressTrackingReducer from '../../redux-store/progressTrackingSlice';
import useIndexDb from './useIndexDb';

// Store setup
const createTestStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: {
      auth: authReducer,
      global: globalReducer,
      progressTracking: progressTrackingReducer,
    },
  });

const testStore = createTestStore();

const wrapper = ({ children }) => <Provider store={testStore}>{children}</Provider>;

// Test case
describe('should test useIndexDb functionality', () => {
  it('should create the IndexedDB database and object stores and add deviceId after calling addDeviceIdToIndexDb', async () => {
    const {
      result: {
        current: { addDeviceIdToIndexDb },
      },
    } = renderHook(() => useIndexDb(), { wrapper });

    await act(async () => {
      await addDeviceIdToIndexDb('1234');
    });

    const db = await openDB('max-maximus', 1);
    expect(db.objectStoreNames.contains('deviceId')).toBe(true);

    const tx = db.transaction('deviceId', 'readonly');
    const store = tx.objectStore('deviceId');
    const storedDeviceId = await store.get('deviceId');

    expect(storedDeviceId).toBe('1234'); // Fails here
  });
});



other code from with in the hook


  /**
   * Will open the IndexedDB and create the object stores if they do not exist.
   */
  const openDb = async () => {
    return openDB(indexDbName, dbVersion, {
      upgrade(db) {
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('deviceId')) {
          db.createObjectStore('deviceId');
        }
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('data')) {
          db.createObjectStore('data');
        }
      },
    });
  };

  /**
   * Will add the device ID to the IndexedDB.
   */
  const addDeviceIdToIndexDb = async (id: string) => {
    try {
      const db = await openDb();
      const tx = db.transaction('deviceId', 'readwrite');
      const store = tx.objectStore('deviceId');

      await store.put(id, 'deviceId');
      await tx.done;

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding Device ID to IndexedDB:', error);
    }
  };




fix add global.structuredClone = require('structured-clone'); in the setUpTests
